# $\pi$ normal to the base $10$

Tags: number-theory, random, pi

If $\pi$ is normal to base $10$, why would we expect to find a string of ten $0$'s in its decimal expansion?

Comment: How do you define "[normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number)"?

Comment: Pi has not actually been proven normal. But even if that were assumed, the simplest answer I can give you is even improbable things can happen simply by chance.

Comment: Well, because it's an immediate consequence of the definition of "normal". Are you sure that's the question you wanted to ask?

Comment: Please don't deface the question. If you do not want your name attached to it any longer, flag a moderator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\pi$ were normal to base $10$, that would mean we would expect to see every string of digits equally often. So, we would expect to see "0000000000" and "7182818284" just as much as each other when we look through the digits of $\pi$. There are $10^{10}$ possible strings of ten digits, so, the hypothesis "$\pi$ is normal" says that if we chose a string of ten digits, and then random location in $\pi$ and then read off the next then digits, the probability of the string read from $\pi$ and the string chosen earlier being the same would be $\frac{1}{10^{10}}$ - that is, every single string would have equal probability of appearing. Thus, if we sampled enough positions, we would almost surely find a string of ten zeros - if we didn't, then the probability distribution of the $10$ digit strings would not be uniform, contradicting the very definition of "normal"

Comment: The definition of normality is in terms of frequency, not probability. It implies that the frequency of 0000000000 among other 10-digit combinations tends to $10^{-10}$ as more digits are considered; in particular, it  becomes positive at some point. There is no "almost surely" here.